# Parameterization of the beta-binomial family Glmmtmb

Tags: beta-binomial-distribution, glmmtmb

I have trouble understanding the documentation for the glmmtmb package (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmmTMB/glmmTMB.pdf)

On page 26, in the details on the beta-binomial distribution, it says:

> Beta-binomial distribution: parameterized according to Morris (1997).
> $V = \mu(1 - \mu)(n(\phi + n)/(\phi + 1))$.

I consulted Morris' paper (Morris W (1997). "Disentangling Effects of Induced Plant Defenses and Food Quantity on Herbivores by Fitting Nonlinear Models." American Naturalist 150:299-327), but I'm still not sure I understand. Can someone explain to me what this means to $\phi$? And what does $n$ represent in the calculation of variance? The number of replicates?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta-binomial_distribution.  In terms of the parameterization used in wikipedia, what they call $\phi$ equals $\alpha+\beta$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I am still a little confused: In Wikipedia it says: Variance=nαβ(α+β+n)/((α+β)^2 (α+β+1)) So, if ϕ= α+β then Variance=nαβ(ϕ+n)/((α+β)^2 (ϕ+1)) Hence to match the formula in the GLMMTMP package: µ(1-µ)=αβ/(α+β)^2 However, in Wikipedia it says that µ=nα/((α+β)) Thanks!

Comment: $\mu$ in the glmmTMB documentation is the expected value of $p\sim \operatorname{Beta}(\alpha,\beta)$ equal to $\alpha/(\alpha+\beta)$.